Having problems with artifacting and odd geometry bending with rigged model
I am new to rigging so I don't know the more in depth details of what I have to do to get it to work right.
Here is a video of what I have... https://youtube.com/shorts/VEwOycbygDw
My first problem is with the weird geometry at the bending points of the legs. As you can see, where the knee bends, you can clearly see some weird warping of the geometry. This also happens at the pelvis and ankle. I think it might have something to do with my topology but I don't know. Here is a picture of that...


The topology is really bad because I built the model a long time ago when I didn't really understand what I was doing but I thought there would be enough for it to at least work properly.
My second problem is with the artifacting that you see throughout the video. Recently I had the same thing happen when trying to render a particle animation without baking it first. Is there a process of backing rigged animation like there is for particle animations?
If need be I can always upload my project files if that would help you guys out.
Thanks for the help bros!


You may be able to fix that if you smooth the vertex groups, also you could remove some edge loops (make it a bit lower poly) and give a Subdivision Surface to your object, maybe share it so that we can give a try: https://blend-exchange.com/

Hey @moonboots! Thanks for responding. Here is a link to the project file if you wouldn't mind taking a look as seeing where I am going wrong. thanks again! https://drive.google.com/file/d/11iu07SKGq61J4U8ZEAs4ikd0Xi8lku6u/view?usp=sharing

Sorry @moonboots I just saw the Blend-exchange link. The project file is now in there as well. Thanks.

You first need to recalculate the normals (ShiftN). The weight is not optimal, first thing for the moment the weight is not aligned with the bones:

Also it is too sharp, you need to smooth the weight, you can do it with the smooth operation:

Also you can weight paint but choose a smooth brush:

Also keep the Strength low:


Thank you so much @moonboots this was exactly what I needed!
